# ActiveRecord association model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to rails and read this [guide](http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html) to get all the info so far.

I have a simple scenario and want to make sure whether or not my associations will work fine.

Scenario:
`User` logs in -> sets up many `groups` -> each group has many `employees`

`User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
end
```

`Group` model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :employees
end
```

`Employee` model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
    belongs_to :group
end
```

**Questions**

- Will this work for the scenario I mentioned?
- I am confused about how to get all `Employees` under a `User`.  What would be the code for that?
- If I need typical CRUD for all these models then would would be in my Action? index/create/update/destroy?  Can someone point me to a good guide on actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also like the has_many through --

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
    has_many :employees, :through=>:groups
end
```

Then you can go:

```
user = User.find(23)
user.employees.do_something
```

Otherwise, you could loop through your groups and its employees (kinda ugly, but will work)

```
User.first.groups.each{|group| group.employees.each{|employee| puts employee.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it together, for the most part, but I think you need to look at has_and_belongs_to_many (which you will frequently see abbreviated as habtm.)  Index, create, update, and destroy would be your CRUD list for Ruby on Rails.  As for a good guide, I like Agile Web Development With Rails, by Dave Thomas.  (When I'm picking up a new topic, I like books - electronic or otherwise.)  It's available online through The Practical Programmers.  The question about "what's a good guide" is pretty subjective, so caveat emptor.